$R$ noetherian s.t $\forall$ non-zero prime ideal $P \subset R$ , $R_P$ is Dedekind $\implies R$ is Dedekind
Definition. For a multiplicatively closed subset of a Dedekind domain $S \subset R$ (i.e. for $s_1, s_2 \in S$ we also have $s_1 s_2 \in S$ and $1 \in S$), the localisation $S^{-1}R$ of $R$ by $S$ is the subring of the fraction field $K = \text{Frac}(R)$ given by elements of the form $\frac{r}{s}$, where $r \in R$ and $s \in S$.
Remarks:
1 The assumption that $S$ is multiplicatively closed guarantees that this forms a ring. There are two main examples of multiplicative sets. Firstly $S = \{1, s, s^2, \dots \}$, for some $s \in R$, where one usually writes $S^{-1}R = R_s$. The other, more interesting, example is to take a prime ideal $P \subset R$ and consider $S = R \setminus P$ (check that this is multiplicatively closed) and we write $R_P := S^{-1}R$ in this case.
2 There is a correspondence between ideals in $R$ and the localisation $S^{-1}R$, where an ideal $I \subset R$ is sent to the (so-called extended) ideal $\rho(I)S^{-1}R$ for the ring homomorphism $\rho: R \to S^{-1}R$ given by $r \mapsto \frac{r}{1}$, and every ideal in $S^{-1}R$ is equal to an extended ideal (note that there may be different ideals in $R$ which correspond to the same extended ideal in $S^{-1}R$).
I am trying to solve this:
Let $R$ be a noetherian domain such that for every non-zero prime ideal $P \subset R$ we have that $R_P$ is Dedekind. Show that $R$ is Dedekind.
My try:
I have to prove that R is integrally closed and that every prime ideal in R is maximal

To prove that $R$ is integrally closed take $\alpha$ in the field of fractions of $R$ : $\alpha \in$ Frac$(R)$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$, with $p(t)$ a polynomial with coefficients in $R$.  Since the field of fractions of $R$ and of the localization $R_P$ coincide we have that $\alpha \in$ Frac$(R_P)$. Then $\alpha \in R_P$, because $R_P$ is Dedekind.
Let $\alpha = r/s$ with $r \in R , s \in S=R\setminus P$. I want to prove that $\alpha \in R$. I am stuck at this point. How do I complete this?

Every prime ideal $P$ in $R$ is maximal:  Suppose $P$ is not maximal, then there exists $M$ such that $P\subsetneq M\subsetneq R$. I am not sure if this M can be taken maximal (does a maximal ideal exist necessarily?) then in the localization  by $S=R\setminus P$ yields $\rho(P)R_P \subsetneq \rho( M)R_P\subsetneq R_P$ (though I am not sure the strict inclusions still hold, I'll suppose they do). Since $P$ is prime. I guess thaat in the localization  $\rho(P)R_P$ is also prime. Then $\rho(P)R_P=\rho( M)R_P$  because $\rho(P)R_P$ must be maximal. Here I would like to conclude that  $M=P$ to get a contradiction, but I don't know how to argue that, since by remark 2, it says that there may be different ideals in $R$ which correspond to the same extended ideal in $S^{-1}R$.


How can conclude this? It would be nice if you could also clear up the doubts in bold in the previous steps.

Yes, it is true under the given conditions, that $R$ is a Dedekind domain. To prove that $R$ is integrally closed, note that $R = \bigcap_{\cal{P} \subset R} R_{\cal{P}}$, thus given an element in $Q(R)$ that is integral over $R$,it follows that such an element is integral over $R_{\cal{P}}$ for each prime $\cal{P} \subset R$, and thus belongs to each such $R_{\cal{P}}$ (since each such ring is given to be a Dedekind domain and hence integrally closed); thus each such element integral over $R$ belongs to $R$, and $R$ is integrally closed. Next, to show that every prime ideal $\cal{P} \subset R$ is maximal, note that $R/{\cal{P}} \cong R_{\cal{P}}/{\cal{P}} R_{\cal{P}}$ and since the latter is a field (a local ring modulo its unique maximal ideal), it follows that $R/{\cal{P}}$ is a field and hence $\cal{P}$ is maximal. Thus $R$ (given to be Noetherian) is a Dedekind domain. (Note that as per your notation, $\rho(P) R_{\cal{P}}$ is the unique maximal ideal $\cal{P} R_{\cal{P}}$ of the local ring $R_{\cal{P}}$, since it is the set of all non-units in $R_{\cal{P}}$.)

The intersection over all prime ideals takes  place inside the quotient field $Q(R)$ of $R$.

Cooìuld you prove that R is equal to such intersection? I am not familiar with that. It looks plausaible, but I think it requires a proof.

why should $\cal{P} R_{\cal{P}}$ be the unique maximal ideal?

why is $R/{\cal{P}} \cong R_{\cal{P}}/{\cal{P}} R_{\cal{P}}$?

Every element $r \in R$ can be written as $r/1$ and so belongs to the intersection. To prove that an element $a/b$ in the intersection belongs to $R$, note that $b \not\in \cal{P}$ for each prime ideal $\cal{P}$ and hence does not belong to any maximal ideal of $R$ (since every maximal ideal is prime); hence $b$ must be a unit in $R$ (since any non-unit in a ring belongs to a maximal ideal). It follows that $a/b \in R$ and the reverse inclusion is proved.  Hence the equality.

To show that $\cal{P} R_{\cal{P}}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R_{\cal{P}}$, it is enough to verify that it is the set of all non-units in $R_{\cal{P}}$.  But this is easy to see, since any unit is of the form $a/b$ where both $a,b \not \in \cal{P}$. Since $b \not \in \cal{P}$ by definition, it follows that $a/b$ is a non-unit if and only if $a \in \cal{P}$.  I hope it is clear now.

We have an objective homomorphism from  $R$ to $R_{\cal{P}}$ mapping and element $r \in R$ to the element $r/1$. Then we have a surjective homomorphism from $R_{\cal{P}}$ to $R_{\cal{P}}/ {\cal{P}}R_{\cal{P}}$.  The composition of these two homomorphisms has kernel $\cal{P} R_{\cal{P}} \cap R = \cal{P}$.  Hence the isomorphism.

What do you mean with "objective"? and why is that last intersection true?

Typo (objective should be injective).  About the equality, one-way inclusion is clear.  For the reverse inclusion, let $a/s \in \cal{P}R_{\cal{P}} \cap R$.  This implies $a/s =b/1$ for some $b \in R, a\in \cal{P}, s \not\in \cal{P}$.  Therefore $a = bs \in \cal{P}$ which implies $b \in \cal{P}$ (since $\cal{P}$ is a prime ideal).  Hence the equality.
